# cmd batch - How to set the "Taskkill" command blocking or non-blocking in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taskkill

We have a group of machines running scripts. Most of our machines fail to finish the task after last weekend.

After comparing the working machines and non-workings machines we find out something weired that the behavior of `Taskkill` command has changed from non-blocking command into a blocking one on broken machines.

For example, to kill a process:
`taskkill /im notexist.exe /f`, if the process 'notexist.exe' does not exist, command will return immediatelly on working machines but keep a 5s timeout before return on broken machines.

They share the same harware and os version and the 'taskkill.exe' version.

The blocking one:
[image: blocking]

The non-blocking one:
[image: non-blocking]

Is there anything in the registry matters? How could I make the behavior consistently?

Comment: The first thing I'd ask is why you are not trying to determine if a process is in operation before you try to terminate it? `%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "ImageName Eq MyProcess.exe" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "MyProcess.exe" 1>NUL && %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im "MyProcess.exe" /T 1>NUL 2>&1`

Comment: @Compo yes it can solve the problem, but I'm wondering what makes the behavior different in my situation.

Comment: That would be a software question, and not suited to this particular site. This is a programming site, and to program it, you'd do it properly, as per my advice above.